# Yii2 не возвращает extraFields

Tags: yii2, rest, activerecord

Имеется класс User с определенными полями. Он наследует ActiveRecord

```
public function fields() {
    return [
        'id',
        'name' => 'full_name'
    ];
}

public function extraFields() {
    return [
        'email',
        'role' => function($model) {
            $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;
            return array_values($auth->getRolesByUser($model->id))[0]->name;
        },
        'city' => function($model) {
            return City::findCityById($model->city);
        }
    ];
}
```

Если я попробую получить данные из него с extraFields, например,

```
http://localhost:8080/api/users?expand=email
```

переопределив метод index в ActiveController,

```
public function actionIndex() {
    return User::find()->where(['id' => Yii::$app->user->id])->orWhere(['parent' => Yii::$app->user->id])->all();
}
```

то extraFields мне не вернуться, но будет возращено, то что написано в fields.
А вот если я верну

```
public function actionIndex() {
    return new ActiveDataProvider([
       'query' => User::find()->where(['id' => Yii::$app->user->id])->orWhere(['parent' => Yii::$app->user->id])
    ]);
}
```

extraFields будут возвращены, но так же будут переданы дополнительные заголовки, которое мне не нужны в данном случае.

Как я понимаю это происходит, потому что all Возвращает не массив пользователей, а массив ActiveRecord. Хотя, если не переопределять метод, то extraFields будут возвращаться, но мне это не подходит, так как запрос должен возвращать только данные о детях пользователя, который сделал запрос, и о нем самом. 

Может я не правильно переопределяю метод Index? Или может надо сделать правило(rbac), которое должно ограничивать отображаемых пользователей.

Comment: А если просто в  `ActiveDataProvider` передать нужные поля которые хотите получить в параметре `columns`?

Comment: Так и делается в в параметра запроса передаются fields и expand. И выводятся только те поля, которые я передал. Тут дело в заголовках и тем, что приходится создаться новую сущность. Хотя может это и правильно и где то в недрах yii2 при вызове запроса тоже так делается, но тогда вопрос какую сущность выбрать, чтобы не передать лишних заголовков в ответ